# Youtube API: Resume Upload *User Authentication Required*

Tags: perl, api, upload, youtube

Im very  tired, three days without sleep and Im stuck at 1 thing,
this youtube upload thing.

this very simple POST procedure always leads to : **"User Authentication Required"**

this is what Im emulating:

```
POST /resumable/feeds/api/users/default/uploads HTTP/1.1
Host: uploads.gdata.youtube.com
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=adf15ee97731bca89da876c...a8dc
Content-Length: 0
Slug: my_file.mp4
```

so far this is what ive done:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;


    my $r = LWP::UserAgent->new()->post(
    "https://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/resumable/feeds/api/users/default/uploads",
        Content_Type => "application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8",
        [
        'POST /resumable/feeds/api/users/default/uploads HTTP/1.1',
            Host            => "uploads.gdata.youtube.com",
           'Authentication' => "Bearer xxxxxx",
           'GData-Version' => "2",
           'X-GData-Key' => "key=xxxxx",
            Content_Length => "0",
           'Slug' => "C:/YouTube.wmv",
        ]
    );

    say $r->content;
```

I tried every Authentication, Oath2, clientLogin,
I can login and get access_token, problem is I can't upload,

I love perl and i hate the fact that there are no support libraries for youtube using perl (there is, but its extremely outdated and direct upload function is not clearly documented or maybe non at all)
please help me, i need this badly and Im really stuck at this, I don't know if the problem is in my part, or youtube's.

Thank you for taking the time to read this, really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you sure your authentication token is valid? I.e., do methods other than upload work? Also, there is no youtube library for Perl because nobody cared to write and publish one. Upload whatever it is you are working on on github and then it will be possible to run your code, see what's wrong and sort things out.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you're using the wrong syntax for your call to `post()`.

The [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent#REQUEST-METHODS) isn't really clear, but I think you want something like this:

```
my $r = LWP::UserAgent->new()->post(
    'https://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/resumable/feeds/api/users/default/uploads',
    Content_Type => "application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8",
    [
        Host            => "uploads.gdata.youtube.com",
       'Authentication' => "Bearer xxxxxx",
       'GData-Version'  => "2",
       'X-GData-Key'    => "key=xxxxx",
        Content_Length  => "0",
       'Slug'           => "C:/YouTube.wmv",
    ]
);
```

You don't need that line which explicitly calls `POST()`. The `post()` method does that does that for you.